# can we priortize the order of search indexing in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have 6-7 indexes and whenever i search in all the indexes i want to set priority to the index in the search

suppose i have 5 indexes with index names

1. user
2. expert
3. admin
4. support
5. superadmin

I want to make sure that the search results me give me first from user not from expert or admin

I have using elastic-search version 6.64

I am not able to find any good documents related to search priority , the priority mentioned in elastic search is mostly related to the recovery of the indexes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible by using the [indices_boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-request-index-boost.html) according to your ES version syntax.

POST index1,index2,....index6/_search

```
{
    "indices_boost" : [
        { "index1" : 5 }, --> index1, will get higher score
        { "index2" : 4 }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I am using a query like this :http://localhost:9200//_search?q=test&from=0&size=10, where i can put this indices boost as i am using a get call for the search

Comment: @VatsalRahul , you can use this in the body of GET search request, if you notice even in the official doc, they are using the GET request, but you can still pass the body :)